# how to make this carousel continious?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone one know how to make this carousel continious ? here is the source http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-carousel.html

`jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        vertical: true,
        size: 6,
        scroll: 4
    });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the jCarousel documentation. The answer is in there.

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

> wrap - Specifies whether to wrap at the first/last item (or both) and
>   jump back to the start/end. Options are "first", "last", "both" or
>   "circular" as string. If set to null, wrapping is turned off
>   (default).

```
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({ vertical: true, size: 6, scroll: 4, wrap: 'circular' });
```

...drives me crazy when the answer is right in the docs...